# Node.js press Media_Play_Pause Key

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vscode-extensions, keypress

So I`m finally trying to learn some javascript.
As a little exercise, I started to write a vs code extension.

I need to virtually press the media_play_pause key.
In Python I can just write:

```
import win32api
win32api.keybd_event(0xb3, 34)
```

I tried multiple different things but nothing worked so far.
The closest I got was:

```
var ks = require("node-key-sender");
ks.sendKey("@179");
```

But it just won`t work.

Comment: Looks like [some other folks](https://github.com/garimpeiro-it/node-key-sender/issues/22) are having this problem

Comment: Thanks for the link!! It works with robotjs: var robot = require("robotjs");
robot.keyTap("audio_pause");